# Session does not get saved while doing Junit test in JavaPlay

Tags: java, session, junit, playframework-2.0

I am implementing Login authentication in my app using [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaGuide4) tutorial.

Here is my authentication function :

```
public Result authenticate() {
    Form<Login> loginForm = formFactory.form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
    if(loginForm.hasErrors()){
        return badRequest(login.render(loginForm));
    }else{
        session().clear();
        session(STR_EMAIL, loginForm.get().email);
        return redirect(
                routes.Application.index()
        );
    }
}
```

I am storing the e-mail of the user in session.

While doing the tests I am not able to get the session in my result.
Here is the code for the Test :

```
@Test
public void authenticateSuccess() throws IOException {
    //setup
    Map<String,String> objectNode = new HashMap<>();
    objectNode.put("email",configuration.getString(CONFIG_LOGIN_EMAIL));
    objectNode.put("password",configuration.getString(CONFIG_LOGIN_PD));

    //test
    Result result = invokeWithContext(fakeRequest("POST","login").bodyForm(objectNode), () ->
                    application.authenticate()
    );

    //verify
    Assert.assertEquals(303, result.status());
    logger.info(String.valueOf(result.session())); *--> Session is Empty
}
```

It is redirected to the index page as the status of result matches but session is not saved.
What can be the problem here ?